# Verify calls using MockMvc in Spring

Tags: spring, kotlin, testing, verify

I currently have a simple controller written in kotlin using spring. When hit, it will call `ServiceA` which will do some validation. If `ServiceA` throws an `AccountNotFoundException`, my controller has a `RetryPolicy` class that will be executed to retry.

However in my tests, I am finding it difficult to verify my `RetryPolicy` execution. Even though I can see that it is being run and executed, I can't verify it since my tests are all using autowired and not being mocked.

Is there a simple way in which I can verify that my `RetryPolicy` is being run in my spring test?

Comment: can u show the code ?